# How to modify default promote pannel to set in_menu true by default in wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

i would like to have 'show in menu' checked by default in an page model
How can i do that ?
Do i have to rewrite all the promote pannel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, setting 'show in menu' by default isn't currently supported by Wagtail, but there's some discussion of implementing this in a future release: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/692